# SCP does not recognize configuration from .ssh/config

Tags: macos, ssh, zsh, scp

I've configure the file `.ssh/config` to make easier connections:

```
Host MyHost
    HostName     my.univ.edu
    User         me
    Port         22

Host cluster
    HostName     thecluster
    User         me
    ProxyJump    MyHost
```

When I do `ssh cluster` everything works well. However, `scp` commands do not work:

```
$ scp cluster:/path/to/my/file .
zsh: no matches found: cluster:/path/to/my/file
```

Any idea why?

Comment: That error seems to be coming from `zsh`, not from `scp`. Is there something in your shell configuration that could be causing this behavior?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't configured my shell specifically. Someone propose a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zsh seems to be doing file globbing here, can you do :

```
scp "cluster:/path/to/my/file" .
```